# NodeJS + Mongo: Insert if not exists, otherwise - update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, exists, updates

I have an object in my mongodb collection. Its schema is:

```
{
    "instruments": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "508510cd6461cc5f61000001"
    }
}
```

My collection may have such object, but may not. I need to check if object with key "instruments" exists (**please, notе, I don't know what value "instrument" is at this time, it may contain any value or an array**), and if exists - perform update, otherwise – insert a new value. How can I do this?

```
collection.find( {  "instruments" : { $exists : true } }, function(err, object){
    if (object) {
        //update
    } else {
        //insert
    }
});
```

doesn't work ((

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to insert one document if it is not found, you can use the `upsert` option in the `update()` method:

```
collection.update(_query_, _update_, { upsert: true });
```

See docs for the [upsert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-behavior) behavior.

An example with the `$exists` operator.

Let's say you have 6 documents in your collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aebff83774152e9ea6b2"), "a": 1 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aec2f83774152e9ea6b3"), "a": [ ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aec7f83774152e9ea6b4"), "a": [ "b" ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aecdf83774152e9ea6b5"), "a": [ null ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aed5f83774152e9ea6b7"), "a": [ 0 ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495af60f83774152e9ea6b9"), "b": 2 }
```

and you want to find documents that have a certain field `"a"`), you can use `find()` method with the [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator ([node docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html?highlight=exists#special-query-operators)). Note: this will also return documents which field is an empty array.

```
> db.test.find( { a: { $exists: true } } )
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aebff83774152e9ea6b2"), "a": 1 }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aec2f83774152e9ea6b3"), "a": [ ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aec7f83774152e9ea6b4"), "a": [ "b" ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aecdf83774152e9ea6b5"), "a": [ null ] }
{ "_id": ObjectId("5495aed5f83774152e9ea6b7"), "a": [ 0 ] }
```

Comment: thats good, thanks, but I actually have no idea what to place as a 'selector'. The best way will be smth like "instrument:[...]", but I don't know what is the current value of "instrument".

Comment: your _selector_ is `{  "instruments" : { $exists : true } }` and the _document_ is what you want to update it to, for example `$set` something or `$push` to append an element to an array

Comment: I just want to use the unique key I've defined on the table to determine update v.s. insert. I don't want to have to specify it again in the selector parameter. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If upsert is true and there are documents that match the query criteria, update() performs an update. See the behaviour http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option - I believe this is better than manually coding this in your application