# Mongoose create document if doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a simple url shortener(Mong db, Node js).
Here is my model:

```
var urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    shortUrl: String,
    longUrl: String,
    created: {
        type: Date, default: Date.now
    },
    clicks: {
        type: Number, default: 0
    }
});
```

I have a function getRandomString6()  that returns 6 random characters string.

```
var string = getRandomString6();
```

I want to implement this "pseudocode" algorithm:

```
1 var string = getRandomString6();
2 if there is document with shortUrl == string
3       go to step 1
4 else
5       create new document with shortUrl=string
```

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose - Create document if not exists, otherwise, update- return document in either case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305623/mongoose-create-document-if-not-exists-otherwise-update-return-document-in)

Comment: @BertrandMartel In my case the document must be created in any case. Not just skip if it exists and not update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy to achieve, this sample should help to get idea

```
function getValidShortUrl(cb) {
    var str = getRandomString6();
    MODEL.findOne({
        shortUrl: str
    }, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) return cb(err);
        else if (doc) return getValidShortUrl(cb);
        else cb(null, str);
    });
}

getValidShortUrl(function(err, shortUrl) {
    if(err) {
        // error
    } else {
        // shortUrl is valid url that doesn't exist in schema
    }
});
```