# Insert multiple none-existed documents to MongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save multiple documents which are tags found on a post indicated by hash sign '#'. I have tags in an array. for example:

`var tags = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'pie']`

I loop over them and convert the to document objects (to insert them into DB). the problem is that I want to insert a **new** document to collection only if it never inserted before. and if it inserted before I want to increment inserted document's `userCounter` property by one.

```
var tags = ['banana', 'apple', 'pie', 'orange'];

var docs = tags.map(function(tagTitle) {
  return {
    title: tagTitle,
    // useCounter: ??????????
  };
});

var Hashtag = require('./models/Hashtag');

/**
* it creates multiple documents even if a document already exists in the collection,
* I want to increment useCounter property of each document if they exist in the collection;
* not creating new ones.
* for example if a document with title ptoperty of 'banana' is inserted before, now increment
* document useCounter value by one. and if apple never inserted to collection, create a new document 
* with title of 'apple' and set '1' as its initial useCounter value
*/

Hashtag.create(docs)
.then(function(createdDocs) {

})
.then(null, function(err) {
  //handle errors
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function findOrIncrease(title) {      
   let hashtag = await Hashtag.findOne({title});
   if(hashtag) {
     hashtag.userCounter++;
   } else {
     hashtag = new Hashtag({title, userCounter: 1});
   }
   await hashtag.save();
 }
```

Usable as:

```
  (async function() {
    for(const title of tags)
      await findOrIncrease(title);
  })()
```

Or if you want to execute all in parallel:

```
  tags.forEach(findOrIncrease);
```

You can speed that up by using mongodbs indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jonas W for response, Also there is another solution I found. I think it might be better (because it's clearer and faster in **performance**) to make some promises based on tags array and resolve tag document from these promises (or reject them with some reasons). Then use `Promise.all()` to make a fullfilled promise providing mongoose documents (created or updated based on some conditions). It's something like this:

```
// some other chains
.then((xxxx) => {
        const hashtagsTitles = require('../../src/hashtags/hashtagParser').hashtags(req.newPost.caption);
        const Hashtag = require('../../src/database/models/Hashtag');

        let findOrIncrease = title =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Hashtag.findOne({
                        title
                    })
                    .then((hashtag) => {
                        if (!hashtag) {
                            new Hashtag({
                                    title,
                                    usageCount: 0
                                }).save()
                                .then(hashtag => resolve(hashtag._id))
                                .catch(err => reject(err));
                        } else {
                            hashtag.usageCount++;
                            hashtag.save()
                                .then(hashtag => resolve(hashtag._id))
                                .catch(err => reject(err));
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => reject(err));
            });

        let promiseArr = hashtagsTitles.map((hashtagTitle) =>
            findOrIncrease(hashtagTitle)
        );

        return Promise.all(promiseArr)
            .then(results => results)
            .catch(err => {
                throw err
            });
    })
    .then((hashtags) => {
        hashtags.forEach((hashtag) => req.newPost.hashtags.push(hashtag));
    })
    //there might be some other chains
```

Also there is a good guide here:
[Mongoose - Create document if not exists, otherwise, update- return document in either case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305623/mongoose-create-document-if-not-exists-otherwise-update-return-document-in)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: I read this post and some others on github. Only thing they noticed as a harm is unhandled errors which I handle them (as you can see in the code). Also I think it is not that complicated. Its just a promise which resolves to a value within the context of some other promises (which might provided by an api) handlers. Would you please tell me what is the main reason that it' an antipattern?

Comment: well you could just chain the promise which makes it more readable. And actually this does *exactly* the same then my code above, just in a few more lines :)

Comment: Using your code how to push each created (or increased) document's ID to an empty array?

Comment: `Promise.all(tags.map(findOrIncrease))`

Comment: true, that works. but how about performance? isn't any way to achieve a better speed? (in performance manner). You consider, now there are only two tags exist in DB collection and it takes about ~7000-11000 ms to complete the tasks. (in none-antipattern way :))

Comment: again: my answer is *exactly* the same, therefore there will be no performance difference.